# Hibernate upgrade issue with ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I've upgraded my application from Hibernate 3 to 4.

I had some thread variables where I keep some information about the client that is trying to login.
The thing is that before hibernate 4, I could access those variables from my custom ConnectionProvider. But now, everytime I try to access those variables I get a null.

1) This is the variable I try to access. Its located in the core of my application.

```
private static ThreadLocal<Client> currentClient = new ThreadLocal<Client>()  {
    protected synchronized Client initialValue() {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Once the client login, I set that thread variable with my Client entity.

2) This is how I create my session factory.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

3) This is how I create the session in my custom ConnectionProvider class.

```
Session s = factory.withOptions().interceptor(new MyInterceptor()).openSession();
```

4) When I execute a query using the session that has been created in my connection provider class, I try to access the thread local variable in the getConnection() method. I could access that value with Hibernate 3 but with hibernate 4 I keep getting nulls.

Also, if I inspect that variable just before doing q.list(), I can verify that the variable has been set. But when the getConnection() method is called, that variable is null.

What could possible be wrong?

Comment: Doing some more testing I realized that most of the variables I set in my custom ConnectionProvider are null.
Strange thing is that in Eclipse I can see that they have a value assigned but when I inspect those values I still get a null.